# How to pass an application apk to jar?

Tags: java, jar, apk

I know that you can use java application on android, but I want to convert apk to jar my application for users who have java. I have proven by changing the termination jar does not work. Any ideas easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally not possible. Simple explanation: Android's application are executing on Dalvik Virtual Machine and phones with java2me don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

yOU want to convert apk to jar.
THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE BECAUSE Android's application are executing on Dalvik Virtual Machine and phones with java2me USES THE jdk.